# Show menu button when making screen smaller

Tags: html, css

im trying to make a responsive website but the menu button is not showing when i make my screen smaller. Here is my CSS code.

Im pretty new to making websites responsive so sorry for this probably easy question but i really couldnt find it anywhere else.

And here is my HTML where i located the menu button and normal menu

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) 
{ 

header
{
    width: 95%;
}

#content
{
    width: 95%;
}

img
{
    width: 95%;
}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) 
{ 

#menu
{
    display: none;
}

.menubutton
{
    display: block;
}

}

.menubutton
{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
    <h2>JARI</h2>
    <nav>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li>Over Mij</li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li>Ervaringen</li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li>Projecten</li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li>Ervaringen</li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <img src="menu.png" class="menubutton" alt="menuknop">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

change css position

```
 @media (max-width: 1024px) 
{ 

header
{
    width: 95%;
}

#content
{
    width: 95%;
}

img
{
    width: 95%;
}

}
.menubutton
{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 980px) 
{ 

#menu
{
    display: none;
}

.menubutton
{
    display: block;
}

}
```

Comment: change my answer check now

Answer (score 0):

CSS reads in order from top to bottom. Inside your media query you're setting .menubutton to display: block, then in the next code block you have display:none

Since you only ever display the menubutton under 980px its entire CSS can go inside the media query

*edit - need to set its initial value to display:none; sorry

https://jsfiddle.net/rzy7L8gh/1/

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){ 

  header{
      width: 95%;
  }
  #content{
      width: 95%;
  }
  img{
      width: 95%;
  }
}

.menubutton {
   display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) { 

  #menu{
      display: none;
  }
  .menubutton{
      display: block;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      right: 0;
  }

}
```